Dashed curved line
I'm new to blender and want to make a curved dashed line and was curious what is a simple way to achieve this.
I've experimented a bit with array modifiers but they give the result in a straight line. I also doubt my copy paste and rotate approach for each cylinder is the way to go.


Use an Array modifier (increase the gap between the instances under Relative Offset or Constant Offset) and also a Curve modifier (make sure that the location of the object is the same as the curve):

